# Inheritance of pure virtual functions implemented in different classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to convert a c# project to c++. I'm trying the following:

```
class IDocInterface
{
 public:
      // implemented in CSpecificDoc
      virtual bool CreateDoc() = 0;

      // implemented in COperations
      virtual void AddOperation() = 0;

      // implemented in CDoc
      virtual void Save() = 0;
};

class COperations
{
 public:
      void AddOperation() {}; // implementation for CDoc and derivates
};

class CDoc : public IDocInterface, public COperations
{
    public:
         void Save() {}; // implemented here
};

class CSpecificDoc : public CDoc
{
public:
      bool CreateDoc() {}; // implemented here
};
```

When I try to do:

```
  IDoc * pDoc = new CSpecificDoc();
```

I get error c2259 cannot intantiate abstract class due to folloing members:
void IDocInterface::AddOperations()  is abstract.

Don't know what I'm missing.

My inheritance structure works fine like this in c# where i use "interface IDocInterface" and "abstract class CDoc".

**Solution:**

Added:

```
class IOperations
{
 public:
     virtual void AddOperation() = 0;
}
```

Then change above to:

```
 class IDocInterface : public virtual IOperations
 {  
 public:
      // implemented in CSpecificDoc
      virtual bool CreateDoc() = 0;

      // implemented in CDoc
      virtual void Save() = 0;
 };
```

and

```
 class COperations : public virtual IOperations
```

Still, I think its a bit strange that the whole thing worked so nicely in C# without the IOperations class...

Comment: Does `COperations` inherit anything?

Comment: what's IDoc in the context?

Comment: Don't forget semi-colons on the end of class definitions in C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless `COperations` inherits `IDocInterface`,  its `AddOperations()` member function is not considered related in any way to the virtual function with the same signature defined inside `IDocInterface`. In this case, C++ compiler will complain about a missing implementation.

However, inheriting `IDocInterface` in `COperations` would create multiple paths of inheriting the same member function. This may be a problem, because functions, even the pure virtual ones, which are inherited through different paths are considered different (this is in sharp contrast to Java and C#'s implementations of interfaces). You fix this problem by marking your inheritance `virtual`, like this:

```
class IWithOperations {
public:
      // implemented in COperations
      virtual void AddOperation() = 0;
};

class IDocInterface : public virtual IWithOperations
{
 public:
      // implemented in CSpecificDoc
      virtual bool CreateDoc() = 0;

      // implemented in CDoc
      virtual void Save() = 0;
};

class COperations : public virtual IWithOperations
{
 public:
      void AddOperation() {}; // implementation for CDoc and derivates
};

class CDoc : public virtual IDocInterface, public virtual COperations
{
    public:
         void Save() {} // implemented here
         virtual bool CreateDoc() = 0; // must be overridden
};

class CSpecificDoc : public virtual CDoc
{
public:
      bool CreateDoc() {} // implemented here
};
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/BO5bkg).

Comment: Thanks for explanation a bit wiser now, but as COperations is also inherited by other classes in the project that has nothing to do with documents, I don't want to inherit from IDocInterface.

Comment: @Jörgen You can split off `AddOperation` into a separate abstract class then, and inherit it in the `IDocInterface`. See the edit.

Comment: OK did and worked, provided that I used the virtual keyword for the inheritance of IOperations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With your declaration of `IDocInterface`, you cannot instanciate a subclass that does not contain *all* `CreateDoc`, `AddOperation` and `Save`.

You need to reimplement them all, otherwise the class will be considered as an abstract class that needs to be inherited from to be used.

If you wanted to have optional member functions in your interface, you can declare them like that:

```
virtual bool CreateDoc() {} // note that you don't need to add ; here
```

And reimplement it where necessary

```
class CDoc : public IDocInterface, public COperations
{
    public:
         // virtual is optional here but usually good for documentation (you can use override keyword instead if using C++11)
         virtual bool CreateDoc() { /* Default implementation */ } 
}

class CSpecificDoc : public CDoc
{
public:
      bool CreateDoc() { /* CSpecificDoc implementation */ }
}
```

It may be a typo but your `COperations` class doesn't inherit from `IDocInterface`, the compiler will not consider the `AddOperation` method as an implementation of the one in `IDocInterface`. As @dasblinkenlight said in his answer, you will have multiple `IDocInterface` inheritance and will have to use the virtual keyword to avoid having several `IDocInterface`. This is called inheriting in diamond I think (at least it was presented to us like that at uni).

```
class COperations: public IDocInterface
{
 public:
      void AddOperation() {} // implementation for CDoc and derivates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to re-implement AddOperation in CDoc so it knows it's the same as the abstract one in the interface:

```
class CDoc : public IDocInterface, public COperations
{
    public:
     Save() {} // implemented here
     virtual bool CreateDoc() = 0; // must be overridden
     void AddOperation() {
         COperations::AddOperation();
     }
}
```

or you can use the using statement in c++11...